# Is there a way to mount docker socket from one to container to another?

Tags: sockets, docker, kubernetes

I'm looking to mount docker socket from one container to another without involving the host. Is it possible? I searched around and couldn't find an example of such a situation. The issue is that host uses a very old version of docker so I setup docker within the container which works okay. Now I need other docker containers to use the socket from the base container and not the host. Is there any way to achieve this (in kubernetes)?

Answer (score 1):

The only way comes in mind is to use hostPath volume with type socket, and mount it into multiple containers:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath

Even if it works you will end up with "other containers" launching containers within your "newer docker" container, which is not a good practice. I would suggest spinning another node with newer docker, connecting it to your master, and spinning the part of load that requires access to docker sock there. You can use nodeSelector to schedule properly:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#step-two-add-a-nodeselector-field-to-your-pod-configuration

You can port this onto k8s further by turning your control container into operator https://www.slideshare.net/Jakobkaralus/the-kubernetes-operator-pattern-containerconf-nov-2017 (use k8s API instead of docker sock)

Comment: I tried the hostpath method but it results in the container crashing in a loop. (I just created a socket on the host owned by root and mounted in inside the container.) pod logs return "can't create unix socket /var/run/docker.sock: device or resource busy". Any ideas?

Comment: I think what's happening is that when I create a socket and mount it with hostPath, there's already a socket inside the container so when I run dockerd, it gives this error. Can't think of a way around this.

Comment: try to create a volume dir, and mount to /var/run/

Comment: I tried that too. I get this error while the daemon start: "Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: listen unix /run/docker/libnetwork/1270301870eb6a20cfef4a5fb13b9e8dcea6298f188876a58de80bcc85a3bf36.sock: bind: permission denied"

Comment: I see, it must be volume dir permissions. Give it 0777. Or make sure it's owned by the user used to run docker, if it's not root. You can test it without k8s, by creating a container with mounted dir - this is what kubelet will do

Comment: Yes so I'm doing the testing locally only with docker. On the host when the directory has 777 permissions it still gives this error: "Failed to connect to containerd: mkdir /var/run/docker/containerd: permission denied"

Comment: Actually that was an error on my part with permissions. It still gives the same error after changing the permissions to 777.